# Harris Laplacian Detector and auto scale selection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection

I do want to get a basic understanding of the Harris Laplacian Detector. I do know the Harris detector but cannot figure out the idea behind the Harris Laplacian Detector.

Let's assume we have two images showing pretty much the same thing but one image is scaled.
We want to find all interest points so we can check them later for correspondance and compute a homography matrix later. Obviously we need a scale invariante interest point detector.

What I think the Harris-Laplacian works (very very abstract; correct me if I'm wrong):

- Apply Harris detector to both images
- Apply a function to each interest points which were returned by the Harris detector
- Keep all points which maximize the Laplacian
- Scale images and apply Harris detector again to both images
- ...repeat other steps...

My questions:

1. What kind of points maximizes the Laplacian?
2. The function I apply to the interest points, what does it look like? Do I really apply it to the interest points or to a patch around the points?
3. I've read the maxima of the function is used. What do we need it for, what does it tell us?
4. It seems this method is kind of bruteforce (scale images, apply harris, check which points to keep, scale images again, apply harris, ...). Isn't this very inefficient?
5. The points which we want to keep have to maximize the Laplacian. What is 'the Laplacian'? Is it the Laplacian operator?
6. If a point maximizes the Laplacian we have a couple of points for each scale. How do we get the final interest points - from which scale do we get them?
7. When does the algorithm terminate?
8. Why do we use Laplacian?

Pretty many questions :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be best if you read Mikolajczyk et al paper about Harris-Laplace and maybe the parts of his thesis; but I will try to answer as much as your questions..

First, why are you asking about points that maximize Laplacian ? 3rd derivative and 4th derivative of the Laplacian will give you information about extremas of Laplacian, however this is **NOT** the case in here. The point which maximizes over Laplacian scales is used in Harris Laplace detector.

Second, *"Apply a function to each interest points which were returned by the Harris detector"*, as far as I know, no you don't apply a function.
 So;

1- Not the maximize Laplacian, but maximize over Laplacian scales is found in this algorithm as F[Laplacian(scale = x-1)] < F[Laplacian(scale = x)] and F[Laplacian(scale = x)] > Laplacian (scale = x+1),this point is accepted as a maxima in Laplacian scale in this manner. You also reject points with values lower than threshold defined. Also Laplacian value is defined with scale for scale i and point x;

F(scale = i)=sigma(i)^2* |(Laplacianxx(x,i) * Laplacianyy(x,i))|

2- The function ? Please comment about it if I am missing a point in here.

3- Since I don't know about the function, I also don't know about its maxima.

4- Gaussian and derivative is linear function. Therefore, by just taking derivative of your Gaussian and get its Laplacian, simple convolution of image by that filter provides you LoG of image. However, there are other Scale invariant point detectors many of which you can use if you think they will perform faster for your case.

5- Yes it is Laplacian but I think I answered about maximum confusion already.

6- You get them all if you don't know about scaling.Otherwise, ,f you ask about choosing which scales and patch sizes for image matching, this is about scale matching. Laplacian measure between scales, will be similar for some values. Look at the first slides of this presentation http://campar.in.tum.de/twiki/pub/Chair/TeachingWs09MATDCV/feature_detectors2.pdf. In addition you may want to read in thesis part titled, 'Scale covariant points'. You will find link at the bottom.

7- You decide the limits of your scale space. After your program finishes calculating for scales you defined(and of course points are detected), your program should finish. I am not talking about two images and corresponding problems yet, you should concentrate on that later.

8- In their paper, they found Laplacian scale is more effective than 3D-scale space. Look another stackoverflow question [Harris-Laplacian-Detector: Corner- and Blob-Detector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615649/harris-laplacian-detector-corner-and-blob-detector). You will also find his thesis in which he explains Harris-Laplace detector clearly.

I hope this helps, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of questions, but I'm not going to answer directly to them because there a lot of them. Instead I would like to said what is "Harris-Laplacian" detector:

**"Harris-Laplacian"** method was mentioned in K.Mikolajczyk, C.Shmitd "Indexing Based on Scale invariant Interest Points", ICCV 2001.

**"Harris corner detector"** is a mechanism from 1988 to find cornders in image. (it is exist hypermarameter to tune in it). It can give you corners and it's orientations.

"Laplacian" is the differential-operator, but in Computer Vision it can mean (ask person with which you're talking) **"Laplacian of 2d Gaus function multipled by sigma^2"**. Where Gausian was written in a form of p.d.f from prob. theory (I mentioned it because e.g. the alternative form of e^{-\pi*x^2} is also usefull, but it is not using in probability theory).
And covariance matrix is diagonal. So it's a nice Gaus function. In the following text I will reference to "normalized Laplacian of 2d Gaussian" as "L".

For example after convolution input image with it you get another image. Such output is called response (term from signal processing or signal filtering).

After estimate poistion of corners via Harris detector in original image, the size of objects in corners are esimated via "convolve" image with "L", and find maximum response in "sigma" space. And this is method with name "Harris-Laplacian"

So: **Harris detector give you a position of corner and it's orientation, convolve with L gives you the size of area of interest near the corne**r, i.e. the size of the corner.

---

p.s. If you convolve the rect signal with "width" equal W then the maxium response you will receive if you convolve it with L with sigma equal to width (observed from practice). 
I don't know **why**. I didn't study normalized laplacian of gaus function directly, but it looks like very intersting function.